# Upload Multiple images to facebook

Tags: xcode

So as the tile say,want to upload multiple images...I can upload one at a time,using a uiimage,I can select the image picker and select a picture from my photo album or take a picture with the camera,and it will work..but now want to upload more than one,I have some ideas,either i can add an other uiimage but that will select the same image on both uiimages and only upload one,so that out of the question,two i can create multiple image pickers or re-write code the for each image i want to upload and just add a button..I know is something simple but can't get my mind around it..so a little help will work..